# Open Layers squished tiles until page zoomed

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Upon initial load the map tiles are squished or sometimes do not appear properly as per image below. This is fixed when the page is zoomed in and out (not the map).

This is when the page is viewed on a 2K screen, any suggestions for how to fix this?

[image]